# Export source code from Power Automate Desktop

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I have created some flow using "Power Automate Desktop".
Is there anyway I can see the action from this application or download the code. So that I can create an application then share it with other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're unable to share within your organisation without a licence (trial or paid) in PowerAutomate.  You at least need to trigger a trial licence to have that feature.

See the text in orange ...

[image: PAD Licence]

If you want to download the source, you can literally select all actions within your flow, hit <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> and then paste the result to a text editor (i.e. like Notepad), save the file and pass it on to another user.

The receiving user can then copy the steps from the text editor and paste them directly into their flow.  The steps will translate.

The annoying part comes if you have a lot of sub flows they'll have to be extracted and saved in a text file one by one and then recreated one by one.

Answer (score 1):

stone age code i use to extract Power Automate Desktop query code to a text file

```vb
Public Sub glhPAD()
           
    xx = InputBox("Enter number of times to run")
    
    For x = 1 To xx
           Open "c:\temp\glhClipboard.txt" For Append As #1
                     Print #1, "==============================================================         "
                     Print #1, Now()
           Close #1
           
           AppActivate "Power Automate": Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
           SendKeys "{F2}": Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
           SendKeys "^c": Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
           SendKeys "{esc}": Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
           Call glhClipboardToTextFile
           
           SendKeys "{enter}": Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:20")
           SendKeys "{tab}": Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
           SendKeys "{tab}": Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
           SendKeys "{tab}": Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
           SendKeys "^a": Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
           SendKeys "^c": Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
           Call glhClipboardToTextFile

           SendKeys "%{F4}": Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
           SendKeys "{Down}": Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
           
    Next x
        
    MsgBox "Capture Done"
End Sub

Public Sub glhClipboardToTextFile()
    '   reference to Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
    '   VBEditor / Tools / References
    
    On Error Resume Next
    With New DataObject
        .GetFromClipboard
        Open "c:\temp\glhClipboard.txt" For Append As #1
          Print #1, .GetText
          Print #1, " "
          Print #1, " "
          
        Close #1
    End With
End Sub
```